# MongoDB query filetering

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, filter

I wanna filter a MongoDb Collection

```
const query = {};

if (args.name) {
    query.name = args.name;
}

if (args.code) {
    query.code = args.code;
}

if (args.isActive) {
    query.isActive = args.isActive;
}

const sort = {
    [sortType]: sortDir === 'down' ? -1 : 1
};

return await this.find(query, {}, {skip: (page - 1) * itemsPerPage, limit: itemsPerPage})
    .sort(sort);
```

I want a more elegant way of constructing query object, I've also tried with $or but the result was not suitable for me. Thx anyway.

Comment: I want to know if your code right now is working or not ?

Comment: It's working fine. But I think that there is a more elegant way of querying with $or, it just fails when all arguments are null, it returns no items, but it should return all(with pagination sure)

Comment: Could you do that `{name:query.name,code:query.code,isActive:query.isActive} = args` I think that should take care about null and undefined values , are you using mongoose ?

Comment: No it returns no items, yes I am using mongoose.

Comment: I think your problem in the second argument not in the first argument I think second argument should be null not empty {}  like this `await this.find(query, null, {skip: (page - 1) * itemsPerPage, limit: itemsPerPage})
    .sort(sort);`

Comment: I've checked your suggestion with mongoDb shell ,it just returns nothing when arguments are null, so the problem is with the query, not the second parameter.)

Comment: db.getCollection('ballots').find({"name":null,"code":null,"isActive":null}) this returns no items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209377/discussion-between-ahmed-kesha-and-hrant-nurijanyan).